# UNet COCO 2017 Model has terrible loss and accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently practicing image segmentation using the COCO 2017 Dataset with UNet architecture using keras and tensorflow, and I'm experiencing terrible accuracy and loss values.

I wrote a function that filters through the dataset selecting specific images of certain classes, and passes these into a list variable that kind of looks similar to the annotations file, containing image file name and image id. This data is then fed into a generator, whose output is a generator variable which I then feed into my model.fit function.

I currently have 3 classes, [background, tv, laptop].

The following code is my model:

```
IMG_WIDTH = 224
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_CHANNELS = 3
epochs = 25
validation_steps = val_size
steps_per_epoch = train_size

##Creating the model

initializer = "he_normal"

###Building U-Net Model

##Input Layer
inputs = Input((IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_CHANNELS))

##Converting inputs to float
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)

##Contraction
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c4)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c5)

##Expansion
u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c8)

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding="same")(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu", kernel_initializer=initializer, padding="same")(c9)

##Output Layer
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation="softmax")(c9)

##Defining Model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])

##Compiling Model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])


##Training the model
results = model.fit(x = train_gen, 
                    validation_data = val_gen, 
                    steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch, 
                    validation_steps = validation_steps, 
                    epochs = epochs, 
                    verbose = True)
```

When I start training, these are the accuracy and loss parameters:

```
Epoch 1/25
  32/7069 [..............................] - ETA: 16:01:30 - loss: 2.2134e-08 - accuracy: 0.0472
```

This is unlike my previous experience with cell nuclei segmentation using Unet. My question is: Is this normal? If not, how do I improve the accuracy and loss of my model? I'm terribly new to machine learning, so any advice or references I can read would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation="softmax")(c9)
```

If you have three classes, you should have activated softmax on an output of size 3, right? I would go with a DENSE layer at the end, like:

```
outputs = model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))(c9)
```

And you should be good.

Comment: Oh my gosh I can't believe I didn't notice that! Thank you for pointing that out! I'm now dealing with much more realistic numbers, with loss starting out at 0.60 and accuracy at 0.55. Are these normal numbers that can be solved with further training? And lastly, why would a dense layer be more preferable for output? Thank you so much!

Comment: @HomerBacanto that is more realistic, but accuracy near to 0.5 actually means you have lots of room for improvement ( since random choice converges to 0.5). For the DENSE layer, it is actually your choice of what to use. That is a classic design in DL. the only important thing is to have as many as your class number in the output.

Comment: Thank you @MikhailStepanov! Strangely though, the Dense layer starts out with a better accuracy/loss ratio than the Conv2D layer. Will a Conv2D be better than a Dense layer after training? Thanks again

Comment: @alift What would these improvements entail? Do you mean adding layers, changing the number of neurons in a layer, or adjusting picking a different optimizer?

Comment: @HomerBacanto that was my bad. If `Dense` layer is applied to 4D tensor like `Conv2D` output, it will return 4D tensor. And outputs of it will be softmaxed correctly, i.e along channel axis (last, `-1`). I was wrong about `Conv2D` with softmax. I didn't check it, but I guess softmax is applied to whole output.But segmentation requires softmax along `-1` axis, as `Dense` actually does.

Comment: @HomerBacanto Nobody really can say. That is the secret sauce you will find with doing cross-validations and experiences.  My first guess would be, seeing you use 7K of data to train, that you need much more data to train your deep network.